# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que se ingresen en orden?

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo una lista doble enlazada y quiero que se ingresen en orden por fecha, pero no veo cuál es el error:

```
void AgrearE(NodoE **inicioptr,char id[5],char nombre[20],char desc[50],int dia,int mes,int anio)
    {
        NodoE *Nuevoptr,*aux ;
        Nuevoptr=crear_e(id,nombre,desc,dia,mes,anio);
        aux=*inicioptr;
        if(*inicioptr!=NULL)
        {
            if(aux->Sigptr==*inicioptr)
            {
                if(aux->fe.Mes>mes)
                {
                    Nuevoptr->Antptr=aux->Sigptr;
                    aux->Sigptr=Nuevoptr;
                    Nuevoptr->Sigptr=aux;
                    aux->Antptr=Nuevoptr;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(aux->fe.Mes<mes)
                    {
                        Nuevoptr->Sigptr=aux->Antptr;
                        aux->Antptr=Nuevoptr;
                        Nuevoptr->Antptr=aux->Sigptr;
                        aux->Sigptr=Nuevoptr;
                        *inicioptr=Nuevoptr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(aux->fe.Mes==mes)
                        {
                            if(aux->fe.Dia<dia)
                            {
                                Nuevoptr->Antptr=aux->Sigptr;
                                aux->Sigptr=Nuevoptr;
                                Nuevoptr->Sigptr=aux;
                                aux->Antptr=Nuevoptr;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Nuevoptr->Sigptr=aux->Antptr;
                                aux->Antptr=Nuevoptr;
                                Nuevoptr->Antptr=aux->Sigptr;
                                aux->Sigptr=Nuevoptr;
                                *inicioptr=Nuevoptr;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }

            }
            else
            {
                while(aux->Sigptr!=*inicioptr && aux->fe.Mes<mes)
                {
                    if(aux->Sigptr->fe.Mes<mes)
                    {
                        aux=aux->Sigptr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(mes>aux->fe.Mes && aux->Sigptr!=*inicioptr)
                {
                    aux->Antptr->Sigptr=Nuevoptr;
                    Nuevoptr->Antptr=aux->Antptr;
                    Nuevoptr->Sigptr=aux;
                    aux->Antptr=Nuevoptr;
                    *inicioptr=Nuevoptr;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(mes<aux->fe.Mes)
                    {
                        Nuevoptr->Antptr=aux;
                        Nuevoptr->Sigptr=aux->Sigptr;
                        aux->Sigptr->Antptr=Nuevoptr;
                        aux->Sigptr=Nuevoptr;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if(mes==aux->fe.Mes)
                        {
                            if(dia>aux->fe.Dia)
                            {
                                aux->Antptr->Sigptr=Nuevoptr;
                                Nuevoptr->Antptr=aux->Antptr;
                                Nuevoptr->Sigptr=aux;
                                aux->Antptr=Nuevoptr;
                                *inicioptr=Nuevoptr;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Nuevoptr->Antptr=aux;
                                Nuevoptr->Sigptr=aux->Sigptr;
                                aux->Sigptr->Antptr=Nuevoptr;
                                aux->Sigptr=Nuevoptr;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        else
        {
            *inicioptr=Nuevoptr;
        }
    }
```

Comment: me gustaria saber que estoy haciendo mal por que no se ordena correctamente por fecha para hacer los respectivos cambios

Comment: Creo que tienes codigo repetido, tal vez podrias evitar tantas comparaciones si haces una sola comparacion para decidir cual fecha es es "mayor", ademas tienes separado el caso donde la lista solamente tiene solo un nodo [if(aux->Sigptr==*inicioptr)] creo que esto no es necesario, podrias evitar este caso y hacerlo de forma generica

Comment: ¿El codigo entero es muy grande como para que lo pongas?, porque asi al ojo no es tan facil donde podria estar el error.

Comment: ¿Ademas no deberias usar la variable  `anio` tambien para odernar las fechas?, no veo que uses esa variable en ningun lado.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Insertar ordenadamente.

El proceso de inserción ordenado en listas suele divrse en:

1. **Localizar el punto de inserción**: recorre los nodos desde tu raíz hasta el último nodo (tope) comparando el valor de entrada con el almacenado; en el momento en que el valor de entrada sea menor al almacenado (o hayas alcanzado el tope) habrás encontrado el punto de inserción.
2. **Crear el nuevo nodo**: debes enlazarlo al nodo del punto de inserción (el primero que contiene un valor mayor al de entrada o el tope) y al siguiente (si lo hay).
3. **Re-enlazar los nodos**: el nodo anterior al punto de inserción debe apuntar al nuevo nodo creado.

Expresado con código más sencillo que el tuyo quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
Nodo *anterior = inicio;
Nodo *punto_insercion = anterior->siguiente;

while (punto_insercion  && (punto_insercion->dato > dato))
{
    anterior = punto_insercion;
    punto_insercion = punto_insercion->siguiente;
}

// Una vez superado el bucle, punto_insercion apunta
// al nodo inmediatamente superior al actual o al tope

Nodo *nuevo_nodo = new Nodo(dato, punto_insercion);
punto_insercion->anterior->siguiente = nuevo_nodo;
nuevo_nodo->siguiente = punto_insercion;
punto_insercion->anterior = nuevo_nodo;
```

En el código de ejemplo anterior estoy asumiendo:

- La lista no está vacía.
- `Nodo` dispone de un constructor que recibe `dato` y el nodo del que copiar enlaces.
- El `dato` a comparar dispone de un operador mayor-que `>`.

A grandes rasgos, el código que he expuesto se comportaría de la siguiente manera, con el siguiente estado inicial:
[image]
Queremos insertar el dato <kbd>k</kbd>, sabemos que este dato es mayor que <kbd>i</kbd> y menor que <kbd>o</kbd>, por lo tanto en el bucle:

1. Primera vuelta, ¿<kbd>a</kbd> > k? Falso, seguimos.
2. Segunda vuelta, ¿<kbd>e</kbd> > k? Falso, seguimos.
3. Tercera vuelta, ¿<kbd>i</kbd> > k? Falso, seguimos.
4. Cuarta vuelta, ¿<kbd>o</kbd> > k? Verdadero, <kbd>o</kbd> es el punto de inserción:
   [image]
   Por lo tanto, creamos el nodo con el dato k copiando los enlaces del nodo <kbd>o</kbd>, de manera que el siguiente de <kbd>k</kbd> será <kbd>u</kbd> y su anterior <kbd>i</kbd>:
   [image]
   Tras este paso, tan sólo nos queda re-enlazar los nodos, son tres nodos afectados:

   - El `siguiente` de <kbd>i</kbd>, que corresponde con `punto_insercion->anterior->siguiente`, debe ser <kbd>k</kbd>.
   - El `siguiente` de <kbd>k</kbd>, que corresponde con `nuevo_nodo->siguiente`, debe ser <kbd>o</kbd>.
   - El `anterior` de <kbd>o</kbd>, que corresponde con `punto_insercion->anterior` debe ser <kbd>k</kbd>.

[image]