# ¿Qué diferencia hay entre rellenar una pila y rellenar una lista?

Tags: c, lista, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

No veo la diferencia entre llenar una pila y llenar una lista. Sé como se insertan nodos en una pila, pero no cómo se insertan los nodos en una lista. ¿Alguien puede explicar la diferencia **en código** de la una y la otra?

```
NODO* aux;
aux = (Nodo*) malloc(sizeof(NODO));
// p un puntero a pila que tiene en su estructura el numero de elementos y la cabecera.
aux->sig = p->cabecera;
// n es el dato que le inserto el nodo
aux->num = n;
p->cabecera = aux;
p->elems++;
```

Un nodo tiene un dato, y un puntero al siguiente nodo o a `null`. Sé que en una pila, para insertar elementos se van apilando por arriba (desde la cabeza) y en una lista el nodo creado debe apuntar al siguiente nuevo elemento. pero en el caso de la lista, no me queda claro.

Gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 5):

Una pila, apila. Se apilan (push) los elementos unos encima de otros y se desapila (pop) el que está encima de todo.

[image]

A nivel de código es muy sencillo de implementar: debes mantener un nodo que sea el tope ("*top*") de la pila y cada vez que insertas un nuevo nodo haces que éste apunte al tope, para acto seguido hacer que el tope sea el nuevo nodo insertado.

---

En una lista, los elementos se insertan en posiciones arbitrarias.

[image]

La implementación es más complicada ya que varía según si la inserción se hace al principio de la lista, al final de la misma o a una posición intermedia; también varía dependiendo de si la lista es simple o doblemente enlazada, circular o abierta. Para una lista abierta simplemente enlazada (que parece ser tu caso) se puede generalizar con los siguientes pasos:

1. Crear el nuevo nodo (*Nuevo*).
2. Asignar como nodo siguiente de *Nuevo* el siguiente del punto de inserción.
3. Asignar *Nuevo* como siguiente del nodo del punto de inserción.

En [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/87953/2742) tienes un ejemplo de implementación.

Comment: No me queda claro el código en el caso de la lista, ¿cómo se insertarían datos en una lista? 1-Declaro puntero de tipo nodo 2- El puntero apunta a cabeza y el siguiente apunta a null, o al siguiente nodo.

Comment: Si tu pregunta es sobre programar una pila y  una lista, deberías haberla redactado como tal. Yo he respondido a la pregunta que hiciste: "*¿Cuál es la diferencia entre pila y lista?*".

Answer (score 2):

Para saber la diferencia, necesitas saber cual es la diferencia entre una **pila** y **lista**.

Los términos listas y pilas no hacen referencia a una [estructuras de datos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estructura_de_datos#:%7E:text=En%20ciencias%20de%20la%20computaci%C3%B3n,ser%20utilizados%20de%20manera%20eficiente.) en particular ni en como funciona cada operación, sino, a un [tipo de dato abstracto](https://users.dcc.uchile.cl/%7Ebebustos/apuntes/cc30a/TDA/#:%7E:text=Un%20Tipo%20de%20dato%20abstracto,como%20est%C3%A9n%20implementadas%20dichas%20operaciones.).

Un tipo de dato abstracto se enfoca únicamente en la interfaz y no en su implementación. Por lo tanto, los TDA solo nos indican las operaciones que podemos hacer en una estructuras de datos.

**1.-** El TDA Lista suelen tener las siguientes operaciones:

- Añadir un elemento en una determinada posición de la lista.
- Eliminar un elemento según su posición.
- Eliminar todos los elementos de la lista.
- Buscar un elemento según su posición.

El TDA Lista podría ser implementando por medio de **arrays** o **listas enlazadas**, sin embargo, en este TDA también podríamos incluir las operaciones de una pila (como `push` y `pop`).

**2.-** Una pila también es un TDA y sus operaciones básicas son:

- Añadir un elemento en el tope de una pila.
- Eliminar el elemento que se encuentre en el tope de la pila.

Este TDA puede ser implementado a través de arreglos o listas enlazadas.

Entonces como puedes ver, los TDA nos sirven para separar la interfaz con la implementación (se enfoca en una estructura de datos en particular y en como funciona sus operaciones).

Sabiendo lo que es un TDA, podemos responder a esta pregunta:

> > Diferencia entre rellenar una pila y rellenar una lista en C

La diferencia es simple. En una pila **siempre** tendrás operaciones como `push` (o *apilar*) y `pop` (o *desapilar*). En cambio, en una lista, no necesariamente debe tener las operaciones de una pila. Todo dependerá de la forma como diseñes el TDA. En algunos casos, en los TDA de una lista puedo incluir las operaciones de un cola o una pila.

> > Sé que en una pila, para insertar elementos se van apilando por arriba (desde la cabeza) y en una lista el nodo creado debe apuntar al siguiente nuevo elemento. pero en el caso de la lista, no me queda claro.

Si la **pila** lo implementas como una **lista enlazada simple** (o también podría ser un vector), insertarás (*operación* `push`) los elementos al principio de la lista.

En cambio, la **lista** la puedo implementar como una lista doblemente enlazada (o también podría ser un vector) e insertar elementos al principio, al final o en el medio.

Otro ejemplo sería una *cola circular*, que también es un TDA y que se lo puede implementar por medio de **array circular** o **lista circular simple**.

**Fuente:**

- [CC30A Algortimos y Estructuras de datos: Tipos de dato abstracto](https://users.dcc.uchile.cl/%7Ebebustos/apuntes/cc30a/TDA/#:%7E:text=Un%20Tipo%20de%20dato%20abstracto,como%20est%C3%A9n%20implementadas%20dichas%20operaciones.).